# statusBar not hiding while playing video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, media-player

I used `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` for hiding status while playing video. But statusBar is displaying.

code:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
[mpviewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:mpviewController.view];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpviewController];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201255/hide-status-bar-while-playing-video-for-iphone

Comment: @Hari: I tried. But didn't working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hide statusBar using bellow line...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

otherwise use this bellow line..

```
mpviewController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

**OR**

```
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

Comment: @Ram use this line it will work.. [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES]; :)

Comment: you tried above all option??

Comment: @Nitin Gohel: If i got answer i should accept. Without getting answer how can i accept? This method is not working for me. Don't tell anything without know?

Comment: @Ram with this code problem must solved dude.. [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES]; or [mpviewController setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];

Comment: @Ram see my answer from this link also.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929951/how-to-hide-the-title-bartop-bar-in-iphone-from-a-view/12932214#12932214